# TextMate 2: How to enable/disable Code Folding

Tags: textmate

Text files shown in TextMate 2 are not currently showing me any options for Code Folding. IOW, there are are no up, down arrows over in the line number gutter on the left that allow collapsing regions of source code.

I assume I may have disabled Code Folding in the past (intentionally or unintentionally).

How does one toggle Code Folding enabled/disabled in TextMate 2?

My Setup:

- TextMate version 2.0-alpha.9503
- OS X 10.9.1

Comment: What type of files are you having this problem with? The bundle that is associated with the type of file you are viewing has to have folding support in it. For example, in the Python bundle, see [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/iolGgPP).

Answer (score 2):

Since TextMate 2, I've also not had any icons in the gutter with regard to code folding.

Currently, I am folding/unfolding through the right-click menu…

[image]

…or by pressing F1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There doesn’t appear to be any source-level support for hiding the foldings column from the gutter. I can hide the arrows by modifying my theme, and setting the alpha component for gutter icons to `0x0`:

```
{   
    gutterSettings = {
        icons = '#FFFFFF00';
        iconsHover = '#FFFFFF00';
        iconsPressed = '#FFFFFF00';
    }
}
```